# How to keep running long process in Flutter, even when user is not interacting with app

Tags: flutter

I'm adding to my App offline capabilities. Once the user clicks download button, the App is downloading some content to device (makes https calls and saves the result). The problem is that the download process is long (few minutes) and since the user is not interacting with the app, the app moves to the background and the download process fails. Coming from cordova world there is a simple plugin that allows running the app in the background. For Flutter, all the I found is the following medium article which looks pretty complicated solution to what I'm trying to achieve:
https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124.

Is there any method more simple to achieve what I need?

Comment: I would recommend using a plugin such as Flutter Downloader which will download files for you in the background: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader

Comment: Thanks for the lead. If I prefer to handle the entire download task by myself, can I do that?